# Hyperledger Composer REST API does not generate transaction interfaces

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I created a business network and tested it in the playground. It all works fine. I can create transactions, assets and participants. When i try and create a rest interface with the composer-rest-server, the participant and asset rest interface is created, but the transactions are not. Any information why not is welcome?

Comment: I deployed the marbles-network example and i get the same problem. Is there a new version or fix for this. It seems to be a product problem?

Comment: can you provide a listing of `npm list -g --depth=0` thanks. This is unusual, I've just tried the Marbles sample network from

Comment: Something seems wrong. I did try to make sure all is installed.

Comment: ├── balance-transfer@0.0.1
├── composer-cli@0.11.3
├── composer-playground@0.11.3
├── composer-playground-api@0.7.4
├── composer-rest-server@0.11.3
├── generator-hyperledger-composer@0.11.3
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── hfc@0.6.5
├── npm@5.3.0
├── to@0.2.9
├── update@0.7.4
└── yo@2.0.0

Comment: npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.3.1 || ^4.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.24
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^2.3.1 || ^4.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.24
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^2.3.1 || ^4.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by uninstalling all Composer component listed in the installing development environment, reinstalling them, installing npm install -g @angular/cli@latest and deploying my network.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide a listing of `npm list -g --depth=0` thanks.  I am using v0.11.3 of Hyperledger Composer.

What you're seeing is unusual, I've just tried the Marbles sample network from and I see the Transaction `TradeMarbles`

```
Marble : An asset named Marble
        Show/Hide
        List Operations
        Expand Operations
    Player : A participant named Player
        Show/Hide
        List Operations
        Expand Operations
    System : General business network methods
        Show/Hide
        List Operations
        Expand Operations
    TradeMarble : A transaction named TradeMarble
        Show/Hide
        List Operations
        Expand Operations
            post /TradeMarble

                Create a new instance of the model and persist it into the data source.

[ base url: /api , api version: 0.1.6 ]
```

Comment: /usr/local/lib
├── balance-transfer@0.0.1
├── composer-cli@0.11.3
├── composer-playground@0.11.3
├── composer-playground-api@0.7.4
├── composer-rest-server@0.11.3
├── generator-hyperledger-composer@0.11.3
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── hfc@0.6.5
├── npm@5.3.0
├── to@0.2.9
├── update@0.7.4
└── yo@2.0.0

Comment: npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.3.1 || ^4.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.24
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^2.3.1 || ^4.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.24
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^2.3.1 || ^4.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.24

Comment: Do you have a suggestion from my output above? Id really appreciate it?